# Template interface containing template struct

Tags: d

Given a struct template, and a template interface that has a member that returns the struct template as well as another member of a different type, what is the correct way to design and implement?

I've the following, but I'm getting compile errors on implementation:

```
struct TemplateStruct(T, U) {
  T a;
  U b;
}

interface IFoo(V) {
  TemplateStruct resulta();
  V resultb();
}

class Foo : IFoo!int {
  TemplateStruct!(bool, string) resulta() {
    return TemplateStruct!(bool, string)(true, "a");
  }

  int resultb() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Looking through the online [Programming in D](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/templates.html) book doesn't cover implementing this sort of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your mistake:

```
interface IFoo(V) {
    TemplateStruct resulta(); // <== Here
    V resultb();
}
```

`resulta()` returns `TemplateStruct`, which is a template, not a full type. You'll need to specify its template parameters, like you do in `class Foo`:

```
interface IFoo(V) {
    TemplateStruct!(bool, string) resulta();
    V resultb();
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to have the struct template parameters be defined at the same time the interface template parameters are?

Comment: Yes, but that will change the signature of the interface: `interface IFoo(V, T, U) { TemplateStruct!(T,U) resulta(); V resultb(); }`